# Implementing the metropolis-hasting algorithm

Tags: python, montecarlo

Over the past few weeks I have been trying to understand MCMC and the Metropolis-Hastings, but I have failed every time I tried to implement it.

So I am trying to use the metropolis-Hastings algorithm to get the Boltzmann distribution from the uniform distribution, but it is not working.

Here is a summary of what I am doing:

1. I draw a random number form the uniform distribution m.
2. I draw another random number form the uniform distribution n.
3. I set dU = n-m.
4. If dU < 0, I accept dU, set m = n , and repeat.
5. If dU > 0, I calculate w = exp(-b*dU), where b is 1/kT, and draw a random number form the uniform distribution r.
6. If w > r, I accept dU, set m = n, and repeat.
   7 If w < r, I reject dU, set m = m, and repeat.

I am a beginner to this field and to python, so I am not sure if the code  wrong or the algorithm is wrong ( probably both.)

My code is attached below. Thank you.

```
import random
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
k = 1.38064852 * 10**(-23)
t = 298
b = 1/(t*k)   U = []
m = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
for j in range(100000):
    n = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    du = n-m
    if du<0:
            U.append(du)
            m = n 
    elif du > 0:
            w = np.exp(-b*du)
            r = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
            if w > r:
                    U.append(du)
                    m = n
            else:
                    U.append(du)
                    m = m
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean with getting "the Boltzmann distribution from the uniform distribution"? What should your final result look like?

Comment: I am sorry if I'm confusing you, but I'm new to this field.

Comment: You don't have to apologise, just help us to better understand what you are trying to do :)

Comment: I am trying to sample energeies that follow the Boltzmann distribution from the uniform distribution. In other words, I want my final result to have a mean of 1/b and a variance of 1/b^2.

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) whether the your code implements your algorithm correctly, and (2) whether the algorithm is correct. I would focus on (2) first. How did you come up with this algorithm? It seems you use the language of statistical mechanics, where U is an energy that depends on a degree of freedom, m. What is that energy? Why do you set `dU = n - m`?  What do you think should be Boltzmann-distributed in the end?

Comment: I am just trying to use the Metropolis-Hastings. These steps come directly from it. m, n are supposed to be different energy states. I set the change in energy to be n-m  or dU. At the end, I think all accepted dU's should be Boltzmann-distributed.

Comment: You are doing a lot more than "just" using the MH algorithm. For example, I cannot find your algorithm on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis–Hastings_algorithm) page. You are making choices for what the stationary distribution should be (Boltzmann?), and also for what the generation and acceptance probabilities should be. But it's not clear what those choices are, which makes it difficult to help you decide whether they are correct.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but it seems that both `m` and `n` are always in [0,1], which means `du` must be in [-1,1]. `du` therefore cannot be Boltzmann-distributed.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem that I had was because m, n needed to be used to generate in a function U(n) or U(n) which then can be used to calculate the change in energy.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are twofold. One is you sample new energy ('n=random()') as dimensionless quantity, which contradicts everything else you're doing (your temperature is in Kelvin, kB is in J/K etc). And second, using values like 10<sup>23</sup> and inverse are not good in physical simulations - you'd better be somewhere within 0...1 range and rescale later. Below I made code which works in electron-volts, sample new energy in eV as well, and produced something which resembles the truth.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kB = 1.0/11600. # eV/K
T  = 300 # K
b  = 1.0/(kB * T) # inverse temperature, eV^-1

np.random.seed(76543217) # for reproducibility

N = 100000
EE = np.empty(N+1) # energy
DE = np.empty(N+1) # delta energy

Ei = 1.0 # initial energy, 1eV
EE[0] = Ei
DE[0] = 0.0
for k in range(N):
    E  = np.random.random()/b # sample energy, in eV
    dE = E - Ei
    if dE < 0.0:
        Ei = E
        EE[k+1] = Ei
        DE[k+1] = dE
    elif dE > 0.0:
        w = np.exp(-b*dE)
        r = np.random.random()
        if w > r:
            Ei = E
            EE[k+1] = Ei
            DE[k+1] = dE
        else:
            EE[k+1] = Ei
            DE[k+1] = 0.0

x = np.linspace(0, N+1, num=N+1)

print(EE[N-30:])
print(np.mean(EE[N-1000:]))
print(np.mean(EE[N-2000:]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(x[N-1000:], EE[N-1000:], 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='Energy')
ax.plot(x[N-1000:], DE[N-1000:], 'go', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='Delta Energy')
plt.show()
```

printed are two last mean values for 1000 and 2000 samples, look thermalized to me

```
0.010188070423940562
0.010666101150488673
```

and graph for E/dE

[image]